# Is using authReducer with auth token a good practice?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt

I have been reading various tutorials on how to use, for example, JWT in a React + Redux app.

In those tutorials, JWT is typically saved in local storage and has an expiry date. This is fine.

However, I encounter some examples using an authReducer that reads from the JWT onload and sets the boolean state isAuthed to true or false. This state is used to handle UI changes such as AuthedNavbar or setting private routes.

My concern here is that the authReducer state becomes stale. For example, if the user keeps the app open, the isAuthed state will still be true, even though the token may have expired.

(Of course, the server-side routes will be protected with jwt so the user will not be able to access resources. However, they will still have a bad UX on the front-end.)

Indeed, this contradicts to the principle of "single source of truth." The auth state is set in both redux and local storage.

Not all state has to be handled in redux. We use react local state and handle router state outside of redux.

Therefore, I think that it is better to use only local storage as the source of truth.

What do you think? Hope to get some suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Don't persist the data `isAuthed` in the storage system. But only place use the `access_token`. Then, even if the user changes it will have no problem. Because you'll be checking it through the database system and verify the `access_token` and know the `isAuthed` from the database as well.

Comment: Are you talking about the server side? My concern is on the frontend.

Comment: Yes, on the frontend you don't need to set `isAuthed`. If you do so, then it's a total security hole.

Comment: Great to get some confirmation. Thanks!!